# debugserver quits unexpectedly every time I run a program in Xcode

Tags: xcode, crash, swift-playground

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               debugserver [1466]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               12.5.1 (18212)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-18212000000000000~4 (12E507)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       842555601
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        lldb-rpc-server [1301]
Responsible:           Xcode [1287]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-07-16 10:48:03.3698 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 12.0 (21A5268h)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F27B101C-8068-145E-293D-A7AF546FA99A


Time Awake Since Boot: 1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  main thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000019287c4e0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1466]

External Modification Warnings:
Process used task_for_pid().

Application Specific Information:



Thread 0 Crashed:: main thread Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libc++.1.dylib                         0x19287c4e0 std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) + 60
1   debugserver                            0x10048a464 std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) + 56
2   debugserver                            0x10048a464 std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) + 56
3   debugserver                            0x100482a8c RNBRemote::SendStopReplyPacketForThread(unsigned long long) + 308
4   debugserver                            0x100471b48 RNBRemote::HandlePacket_last_signal(char const*) + 140
5   debugserver                            0x10047314c RNBRemote::HandlePacket_v(char const*) + 1792
6   debugserver                            0x100481500 RNBRemote::HandleReceivedPacket(RNBRemote::PacketEnum*) + 356
7   debugserver                            0x1004592c4 RNBRunLoopGetStartModeFromRemote(RNBRemote*) + 184
8   debugserver                            0x10045b6b8 main + 4652
9   dyld                                   0x100c250fc start + 520

Thread 1:: read gdb-remote packets thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1928da504 read + 8
1   debugserver                            0x10048d468 RNBSocket::Read(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) + 96
2   debugserver                            0x100481c5c RNBRemote::ThreadFunctionReadRemoteData(void*) + 196
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19291543c _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1929100d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: exception monitoring thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1928d9914 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1928d9cc4 mach_msg + 76
2   debugserver                            0x100491430 MachException::Message::Receive(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 188
3   debugserver                            0x10049c6b4 MachTask::ExceptionThread(void*) + 288
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19291543c _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1929100d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: kqueue thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1928df8b0 kevent + 8
1   debugserver                            0x10045d844 kqueue_thread(void*) + 152
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19291543c _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1929100d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: child process status watcher thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1928dd0a4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192915a14 _pthread_cond_wait + 1240
2   debugserver                            0x100468c40 PThreadEvent::WaitForSetEvents(unsigned int, timespec const*) const + 60
3   debugserver                            0x10045eb1c DNBProcessWaitForEvents(int, unsigned int, bool, timespec*) + 76
4   debugserver                            0x100469890 RNBContext::ThreadFunctionProcessStatus(void*) + 232
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19291543c _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1929100d4 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000016f9a9ea8   x1: 0x000000016f9aa0b8   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x000000016f9aa1f1
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x000000016f9a9e30   x6: 0x0000000000000029   x7: 0x000000000000003e
    x8: 0x0000000000000054   x9: 0x00278001004c53f0  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000008
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000002
   x16: 0x00200001004c5320  x17: 0x00000001004c5320  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016f9a9ea8
   x20: 0x000000016f9a9f88  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x00000001004b0168  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x00000000000070da  x25: 0x0000000000000020  x26: 0x00000001004b0147  x27: 0x00000000000000a0
   x28: 0x00000000000005b9   fp: 0x000000016f9a9e90   lr: 0x3c5c00010048a464
    sp: 0x000000016f9a9e80   pc: 0x000000019287c4e0 cpsr: 0x20000000
   far: 0x000000016fbd7000  esr: 0xf200c472 (Breakpoint) pointer authentication trap DA

Binary Images:
       0x192857000 -        0x1928c0fff libc++.1.dylib (*) <e5324efb-096c-37bb-ba81-af1cb5162ea2> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
       0x100454000 -        0x1004c3fff com.apple.dt.Xcode (12.5.1) <3bdecb4d-7b7e-36b4-ab9a-18b785711d97> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver
       0x100c20000 -        0x100c7bfff dyld (*) <d453e645-e157-37a2-8520-9da57a0c71f3> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1928d8000 -        0x19290dfff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <56136a5e-cfc9-3fc9-8617-e3941f393c78> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x19290e000 -        0x19291afff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <9891d5d0-65ec-33af-9bc0-4fd70f166924> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 14
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=623.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=623.1M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=557.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=557.5M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           163.2M       16 
MALLOC guard page                   96K        5 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.1M        5 
Stack                             10.1M        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G        1 
__AUTH                             214K       47 
__AUTH_CONST                      2882K      125 
__DATA                            5018K      117 
__DATA_CONST                      3224K      127 
__DATA_DIRTY                       233K       55 
__LINKEDIT                       545.4M        4 
__OBJC_CONST                       260K       30 
__OBJC_RO                         80.8M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2976K        1 
__TEXT                            77.7M      133 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
mapped file                         48K        1 
shared memory                       64K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.3G      682 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.9G      682 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"debugserver","timestamp":"2021-07-16 10:48:03.00 -0400","app_version":"12.5.1","slice_uuid":"3bdecb4d-7b7e-36b4-ab9a-18b785711d97","adam_id":"497799835","build_version":"18212","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.apple.dt.Xcode","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"etl_key":"3","bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.0 (21A5268h)","incident_id":"2AB95BAF-3CF3-4FDC-9CA6-E40F7FCE6EA0","name":"debugserver"}
{
  "uptime" : 1100,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-07-16 10:48:03.0921 -0400",
  "procRole" : "Unspecified",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 209,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookAir10,1",
  "coalitionID" : 932,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.0",
    "build" : "21A5268h",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-07-16 10:48:03.3698 -0400",
  "incident" : "2AB95BAF-3CF3-4FDC-9CA6-E40F7FCE6EA0",
  "pid" : 1466,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "debugserver",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/SharedFrameworks\/LLDB.framework\/Versions\/A\/Resources\/debugserver",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"12.5.1","CFBundleVersion":"18212","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.dt.Xcode"},
  "buildInfo" : {"ProjectName":"IDEFrameworks","SourceVersion":"18212000000000000","ProductBuildVersion":"12E507","BuildVersion":"4"},
  "storeInfo" : {"storeCohortMetadata":"7|date=1626399000000&sf=143441&pgtp=Search&pgid=osx&prpg=Genre_182860&ctxt=Search&issrch=1&imptyp=card&kind=macSoftware&lngid=1","itemID":"497799835","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"3CB280EC-A61D-51EE-9331-BFE200816C16","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"842555601"},
  "parentProc" : "lldb-rpc-server",
  "parentPid" : 1301,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
  "crashReporterKey" : "F27B101C-8068-145E-293D-A7AF546FA99A",
  "responsiblePid" : 1287,
  "responsibleProc" : "Xcode",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x000000019287c4e0","rawCodes":[1,6753338592],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":1466},
  "asi" : {"dyld":[]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":1},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":14},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":1},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":28904,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6167371432},{"value":6167371960},{"value":1},{"value":6167372273},{"value":0},{"value":6167371312},{"value":41},{"value":62},{"value":84},{"value":11118265880040432,"symbolLocation":11118261580070928,"symbol":"vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >"},{"value":2},{"value":8},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":16},{"value":2},{"value":9007203554710304,"symbolLocation":9007199254741016,"symbol":"vtable for std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >"},{"value":4299969312,"symbolLocation":24,"symbol":"vtable for std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >"},{"value":0},{"value":6167371432},{"value":6167371656},{"value":1},{"value":4299882856},{"value":0},{"value":28890},{"value":32},{"value":4299882823},{"value":160},{"value":1465}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4349351344432784484},"cpsr":{"value":536870912},"fp":{"value":6167371408},"sp":{"value":6167371392},"esr":{"value":4060136562,"description":"(Breakpoint) pointer authentication trap DA"},"pc":{"value":6753338592,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":6169653248}},"name":"main thread","queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":152800,"symbol":"std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":222308,"symbol":"std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long)","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":222308,"symbol":"std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long)","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":191116,"symbol":"RNBRemote::SendStopReplyPacketForThread(unsigned long long)","symbolLocation":308,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":121672,"symbol":"RNBRemote::HandlePacket_last_signal(char const*)","symbolLocation":140,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":127308,"symbol":"RNBRemote::HandlePacket_v(char const*)","symbolLocation":1792,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":185600,"symbol":"RNBRemote::HandleReceivedPacket(RNBRemote::PacketEnum*)","symbolLocation":356,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":21188,"symbol":"RNBRunLoopGetStartModeFromRemote(RNBRemote*)","symbolLocation":184,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":30392,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":4652,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":20732,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":2}]},{"id":28906,"name":"read gdb-remote packets thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":9476,"symbol":"read","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":234600,"symbol":"RNBSocket::Read(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&)","symbolLocation":96,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":187484,"symbol":"RNBRemote::ThreadFunctionReadRemoteData(void*)","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29756,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":8404,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":28908,"name":"exception monitoring thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":6420,"symbol":"mach_msg_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":7364,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":250928,"symbol":"MachException::Message::Receive(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)","symbolLocation":188,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":296628,"symbol":"MachTask::ExceptionThread(void*)","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29756,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":8404,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":28913,"name":"kqueue thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":30896,"symbol":"kevent","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":38980,"symbol":"kqueue_thread(void*)","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29756,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":8404,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":28914,"name":"child process status watcher thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":20644,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":31252,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait","symbolLocation":1240,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":85056,"symbol":"PThreadEvent::WaitForSetEvents(unsigned int, timespec const*) const","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":43804,"symbol":"DNBProcessWaitForEvents(int, unsigned int, bool, timespec*)","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":88208,"symbol":"RNBContext::ThreadFunctionProcessStatus(void*)","symbolLocation":232,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":29756,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":8404,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6753185792,
    "size" : 434176,
    "uuid" : "e5324efb-096c-37bb-ba81-af1cb5162ea2",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++.1.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++.1.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4299505664,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "12.5.1",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
    "size" : 458752,
    "uuid" : "3bdecb4d-7b7e-36b4-ab9a-18b785711d97",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/SharedFrameworks\/LLDB.framework\/Versions\/A\/Resources\/debugserver",
    "name" : "debugserver",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "18212"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4307681280,
    "size" : 376832,
    "uuid" : "d453e645-e157-37a2-8520-9da57a0c71f3",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6753714176,
    "size" : 221184,
    "uuid" : "56136a5e-cfc9-3fc9-8617-e3941f393c78",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6753935360,
    "size" : 53248,
    "uuid" : "9891d5d0-65ec-33af-9bc0-4fd70f166924",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=623.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=623.1M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=557.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=557.5M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           163.2M       16 \nMALLOC guard page                   96K        5 \nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.1M        5 \nStack                             10.1M        5 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        1.0G        1 \n__AUTH                             214K       47 \n__AUTH_CONST                      2882K      125 \n__DATA                            5018K      117 \n__DATA_CONST                      3224K      127 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       233K       55 \n__LINKEDIT                       545.4M        4 \n__OBJC_CONST                       260K       30 \n__OBJC_RO                         80.8M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2976K        1 \n__TEXT                            77.7M      133 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                         48K        1 \nshared memory                       64K        4 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              2.3G      682 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.9G      682 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "name" : "main thread",
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS" : "60c88ac7e7d17206e1f95943"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000055
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "60ca460c10d03d047ed95dfe"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000099
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000092
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS" : "60c8a862e7d17206e1f95953"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 250000122
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 7429.0.133.121.1, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi, wl0: May 11 2021 22:21:31 version 18.20.284.1.7.8.108 FWID 01-9dd86976
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
```

I'm still learning Swift and Xcode, so I'm not sure what else is needed. If anything else is, please let me know, and I will edit this question.

The code I am running is the default playground code, where UIKit is imported, and a single variable is declared. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode. I am also running the Monterey beta, so that may be causing the issue. My Xcode version is Xcode 12.5.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Monterey beta seems to cause the issue. Mine as well.